# How to I exempt my old home page from a directory-wide redirect in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to exempt my old home page from a directory-wide redirect in htaccess. Here's what I have that isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{http_host} ^old.com?$ [nc]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new.com/archive?id=$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try a / for the request_uri, ie.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{http_host} ^old.com?$ [nc]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new.com/archive?id=$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Comment: is it not working on access www.old.com/index.html or because it's for the index i.e. you want it for if they're going to www.old.com ?